# Is it possible to monitor NTP through SNMP in Linux

Tags: linux, snmp, ntp

Is it possible to monitor the NTP drift value ( I mean measuring the time difference between the NTP server and the server that I am trying to monitor) using SNMP.

Answer (score 1):

You can add, custom snmp oids to snmpd.conf and then request the oid as answer the drift value.You might write a shell script which triggers by the oid call to snmpd. Then it will response the result you might want to see. If i understand your question right. This might solve it. Anything you can do on console can call it and show its output as response via snmpd.conf.

Comment: might also look into the Nagios script called check_ntp